# Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of mappings $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ for which $f(m) \ge f(n)$ for $m \le n$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of mappings $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ for which $f(m) \ge f(n)$ for $m \le n$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is countable.

---

**My attempt:**

For all $f\in \mathcal F$, $f$ will be eventually constant, i.e. there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $f(n)=f(N)$ for all $n>N$. Let $N_f$ be the least element of such $N$ for each $f\in \mathcal F$.

Let $\operatorname{Seq}(\Bbb N)$ be the set of all finite sequences from $\Bbb N$. We define a mapping $G:\mathcal F \to \operatorname{Seq}(\Bbb N)$ by $G(f)=f_{\restriction \{0,\cdots,N_f\}}$. Then $G$ is clearly injective. Hence $|\mathcal F| \le |\operatorname{Seq}(\Bbb N)|$. We already know that $\operatorname{Seq}(\Bbb N)$ is countable. It follows that $\mathcal F$ is countable.

---

My questions:

1. Does my proof look fine or contain gaps?
2. I feel that this proof depends on the theorem *If $A$ is countable, then the set of finite sequences from $A$ is countable*, which in turn requires several *heavy* lemmas. I would like to ask  for a simpler proof.

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the functions that are constant starting at $n$. Show each $A_n$ is countable and thus $\cup_n A_n$, which is a superset of what you are looking for, is countable.

Comment: Here is my reasoning (I am asking for correction):

Let us fix $n=n_0$. Then, $\exists$ only a finite no. of $m$ s.t $m \leq n$. $f(m)$ being a map, $f$ can associate $m$ 's with only a finite number of images. Hence, we run the union over all finite $n$ 's, we get the union of family of finite/countable (slight confusion here) sets. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @mathworker21 , is this what you implied, or otherwise?

Comment: "f(m) being a map" i don't know what that means

Comment: @mathworker21 I meant the function $f$ being a mapping from $ \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, it can assign only a single value to each $m$. [ i.e. $f(m)=k, f(m) = l$ where $k \neq l$ isn't possible.]

Comment: I tried to write an answer using the helpful idea of @mathworker21 without writing down a formal "map" or bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f$ is a member of $\mathbb{N}^{N_f} \times \{c_f\}^\mathbb{N}$ (where $c_f$ is the final constant), which is a countable set for any fixed $(c_f, N_f)$ pair. There are only $\mathbb{N}^2$ such pairs. A countable union of countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly simpler proof (depending on your viewpoint) is to construct an explicit injection $\mathcal{F}\to\mathbb{N}$ by
$$
f\in\mathcal{F}\mapsto 2^{f(0)}\times 3^{f(0)-f(1)}\times 5^{f(1)-f(2)}\times\cdots
$$
The product is finite by exactly the same reason as that of the existence of $N_f$.  Note this is only an injection, since it doesn't contain odd numbers >1, for example.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach written for fun and/or clarity:

This produces a sequence with maximum $f(1)$ that eventually becomes constant (as pointed out in the OP). Let us just consider the cases where $f(1) = 3$ for concreteness. This means all sequences that are of one of the following forms:

- all $3$s
- finitely many $3$s, all $2$s
- finitely many $3$s, finitely many $2$s, all $1$s

Respectively, the number of these sequences is:

- one
- countably infinite: one for each possible place at which it switches from $3$ to $2$, which has size $|\mathbb{N}|$
- countably infinite: one for each possible place at which it switches from $3$ to $2$, and another for each possible place at which it switches from $2$ to $1$, which has size $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}|$

Altogether, we conclude that the number of sequences with $f(1) = 3$ constitutes a countably infinite collection: it corresponds to a a finite union of countable sets. But, a similar line of reasoning works for $f(1) = n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since the countable union of countable sets is countable, the assertion follows.

Comment: [Note that the case of "finitely many $3$s, all $1$s" is not explicitly listed; however, it could be viewed as a subcase of the third bullet point - in which "finitely many $2$s" means "no $2$s" - or enumerated separately, depending on one's preferences around proof-writing and structure.]